# Getting an accurate Facebook like count

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm attempting to determine the number of likes for a specific url however have found that Facebook is returning zero likes via the graph api, rest api and fql query despite showing 91 likes via its own button.

My question is how to access the data-source from which facebook like buttons derive their count?

[Graph](http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.originalsourcevote.co.uk/orange_tracker.php)

[Rest](http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=https://www.originalsourcevote.co.uk/orange_tracker.php)

[FQL](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+url%2C+normalized_url%2C+share_count%2C+like_count%2C+comment_count%2C+total_count%2C+commentsbox_count%2C+comments_fbid%2C+click_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D%22https://www.originalsourcevote.co.uk/orange_tracker.php%22&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAL8cvwBNHeN9k8ejzMzxZCTpEZATNKyotkekCginLomn1VuKaHbtJm0jwuA2NMKMmwp5HZAWTHzk2smxVjjtJS2sAUMmb7J4wiUlLgg)

[Debugger throws no potential issues](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.originalsourcevote.co.uk%2Forange_tracker.php)

All the above return zero likes, or simply don't return anything. [Enter the url here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) however (and enable the button_count layout): 
and you'll see 91 likes on the button_count.

Is there anywhere I can access this data from Facebook?

I'd really rather not have to attempt scraping the value out of the like button's iframe!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You retrieving number of likes for the wrong URL.

In OpenGraph tags for `https://www.originalsourcevote.co.uk/orange_tracker.php` `og:url` property points to Canonical URL `https://www.originalsourcevote.co.uk/`.

As you can see in the results from Graph API (next query will return correct number of shares/likes):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=https://www.originalsourcevote.co.uk/
```

FQL and Rest will both return correct results for Canonical URL.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately since i've reset the og:url it seems to have set the count back to zero somehow as i now have 5 likes for the page. At least it's tracking them correctly now. Thanks again.